# Getting rid of gcc shift by negative warning

Tags: c++, gcc

I have some code that looks like:

```
template<unsigned int A, unsigned int B>
int foo() {
  int v = 1;
  const int x = A - B;
  if (x > 0) {
    v = v << x;
  }
  bar(v);
}
```

gcc will complain about x being negative for certain instantiations of A, B; however,  I do perform a check to make sure it is non-negative.  What's the best way around this?  I know I can cast `x` to be `unsigned int` but that will cause warnings about `x` being larger than the width of `v` (since it is casting a negative number to be positive).  I know there is a work-around that involves creating a new templatized `shift` function, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since A and B are known at compile time, not only can you get rid of your warning, but you can also get rid of a runtime `if`, without any casts, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template< unsigned int A, unsigned int B >
struct my
{
    template< bool P >
    static void shift_if( int & );

    template<>
    static void shift_if< false >( int & ) {}

    template<>
    static void shift_if< true >( int & v ) { v <<= A - B; }

    static void op( int & v ) { shift_if< (A > B) >( v ); }
};

template< unsigned int A, unsigned int B >
int foo()
{
    int v = 1;
    my< A, B >::op( v );
    return v;
}

int main() {
    cout << foo< 1, 3 >() << endl;
    cout << foo< 3, 1 >() << endl;
    cout << foo< 300, 1 >() << endl;
    cout << foo< 25, 31 >() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A very good solution. though it would need tweaking to address the (A - B >= 32) issue. BTW, the if would likely be factored out anyway since the compiler can detect that it will never happen.

Comment: @Evan Teran, Thanks!  I noticed the shift-wrap issue, but OP's original code let it wrap so I assumed that's what he wanted. I suspect you're right about compiler optimization but in my version the expression A - B is unsigned thus avoiding a warning.

Comment: Ideally, I'd want the code to warn me if I was shifting by too much if that number was positive and not warn me at all if it were negative (since it wouldn't get executed).  I guess there is no way of getting around it but this way.  Good to know.

Comment: You can make the excessive positive shift an error by declaring, but not defining extra specializations.

Answer (score 1):

why not make x an unsigned char type and cast it? surely you don't need to shift more than 255 bits?

```
const unsigned char x = static_cast<unsigned char>(A - B);
```

or perhaps use masking to ensure that the shift is in bounds like this:

```
const unsigned int x = static_cast<unsigned int>(A - B) & 0x1f; // limit A-B to have a range of (0 - 31)
```

EDIT:

in response to the comment here's an idea:

```
template<unsigned int A, unsigned int B>
int foo() {
  int v = 1;
  const int x = A - B;
  if (x > 0) {
    v = v << (static_cast<unsigned int>(x) & 0x1f);
  }
  bar(v);
}
```

NOTE: you can replace 0x1f with something like: (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(T) - 1)

EDIT: in response to the latest comment, this code does not issue any warning compiling with: g++ -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic test.cc -o test

```
#include <iostream>

template<unsigned int A, unsigned int B>
int foo() {
  int v = 1;
  const int x = A - B;
  if (x > 0) {
    v = v << (static_cast<unsigned int>(x) & 0x1f);
  }
  return v;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << foo<1, 3>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo<3, 1>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo<300, 1>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo<25, 31>() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I believe if the right hand side were negative, it would cast it to an `unsigned int` which would make it positive.  I don't want to do run the code if the result of `A-B` is negative.

Comment: Since it knows the values at compile time, anything number greater than 32 will flag another warning about shifting by a number greater than the type width. So while this does indeed solve the negative problem, it will raise that second warning.

Comment: I am limiting the value to be 0-32, so there should be no warning

Comment: ahh, sorry, I miss-read that the mask.  I thought it was masking the negative sign.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
const short unsigned int x = A - B;
```

It's cutting off a lot more bits than need to be cut off, but if your values of A - B are small enough...

Comment: To be more concrete: I have `A == 25` and `B == 31`.  That gives me `x == -6` which is looks like `111...11010` and truncating it would still give me a rather large number